# Find the nth greatest value per group in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to find the nth greatest value in each group in a table; is there an efficient way to do this in SQL? (specifically Google BigQuery, if that's relevant)

For example, suppose we had a table `sales` with two fields, `customer_id` and `amount`, where each record corresponds to the sale of an item to a customer for a given amount. If I wanted the top sale to each customer, I could do

```
SELECT customer_id, MAX(amount) top_amount
FROM sales
GROUP BY customer_id;
```

If I instead wanted the 5th greatest value for each customer, is there an efficient/idiomatic way to do that in SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yet another option with use of `nth_value()` function

```
SELECT distinct customer_id, 
  nth_value(amount, 5) over win top_5th_amount
FROM sales
window win as (partition by customer_id order by amount desc rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following )
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider below approach

```
SELECT customer_id, array_agg(amount order by amount desc limit 5)[safe_offset(4)] top_5th_amount
FROM sales
GROUP BY customer_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `qualify`:

```
select s.*
from sales s
where 1=1
qualify row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by amount desc) = 5;
```

Note:  You question is unclear on how to handle tied amounts.  This treats them as separate amounts (so the 5th could be the same as the 1st).  If you want the 5th largest distinct value, use `dense_rank()` instead.